# Ionic Cordova app black bars on iphone x on xcode 10 but same code produces correct view on xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 (/Users/jscotto/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   ios-sim    : 6.1.2
   NodeJS     : v9.11.1 (/Users/jscotto/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/node)
   npm        : 3.10.10
   OS         : macOS
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

This issue is super strange. On xcode 9.4.1 my app displays on iphone X and XR without black bars but running the same exact code on Xcode 10 it will have black bars on both the top and bottom. I am completely lost and have been trying to fix this for the past 6 hours. My app is completely fresh and the following are my current plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```